# WSS audiences dont show all AD Groups

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2007, domain-controller

Not all of my AD Groups are showing in the Audience list. I want to create a new audience based on if the user is in a group. Some AD groups show up, and others don't. Many the newer ones do not show up. My connection is pulling (im pretty sure) the whole AD via primary domain controller.

MOS2007 win2003

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your profile imports are not working properly. I would try performing a full profile import manually and see if that fixes your problem.

Also - make sure you have full profile imports scheduled occasionally, not just incrementals.

Comment: How much grinding would a full import do? I have that scheduled off, I've only done that once and do an incremental every night when potentially no one is on.

Comment: @Mike - it is pretty resource (CPU, network and disk I/O) intensive while running, but the runtime is fairly short - ours runs in less than 5 minutes for 11,000 user profiles. I typically do incrementals every night, and a full every weekend overnight.

Comment: I appreciate the response, I will follow up with you soon, just have to wait for the weekend to hit :)

Comment: That worked, I can see all my Security and Distribution Groups after a full import. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Full import in the User profiles and properties section.  This seems to be the case, even if your Security groups are outside the scope of the import connection.  It also seems necessary to do a full import to correctly get an up to date group membership.

Not entirely sure what an incremental import does if it doesn't import changes...